why are records not deleted from database
I am running this function to delete the records from the database. I received the message in response as 'successfully deleted', but the records are not deleted from the database table.
public function deleteInventory()
    {
        $token = $this->request->getPost('token');
        $dateReceived = $this->request->getPost('date');

        if ($token) {
            $resultarray = validateToken($token);
            if ($resultarray['success'] == 'True') {
                try {
                    $stocktable = new InventoryStock();
                    $builder = $stocktable->builder();

                    // Fetch records based on the date received
                    $records = $builder->where('date_received', $dateReceived)->findAll();

                    // Check if records exist
                    if (!empty($records)) {
                        // Array to hold the IDs
                        $ids = [];

                        // Loop through and collect IDs
                        foreach ($records as $record) {
                            // Check if $record is an object or array
                            if (is_array($record)) {
                                $ids[] = $record['id'] ?? null; // Safe access for array
                            } elseif (is_object($record)) {
                                $ids[] = $record->id ?? null; // Safe access for object
                            }
                        }

                        // Delete records based on collected IDs
                        $deletedCount = $builder->whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
                        if ($deletedCount) {
                            // Successful deletion
                            return json_encode([
                                "success" => "True",
                                "message" => $deletedCount . " records deleted successfully.",
                                "ids" => $ids
                            ]);
                        } else {
                            // No records deleted
                            return json_encode([
                                "success" => "False",
                                "message" => "Deletion failed or no records were deleted."
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return json_encode(["error" => "Exception", "message" => $e->getMessage()]);
                }
            } else {
                return json_encode($resultarray);
            }
        } else {
            return json_encode(["error" => "Exception", "message" => "Token Missing"]);
        }
    }


The response message shows "records deleted successfully", but in the database the records still exist.

you write .I receive message in response that successfully deleted but records not delete from the database table. and after the code block you write in response i found that deleted records but from database records exists your text. Can you please edit your Question to clarify this? thanks.

@Vickel after running the function i receive message in response
"message" :" 200 records deleted successfully.",
but records actually not deleted from database

Do you have Soft Deletes enabled? Do you have Foreign keys that restrict items being removed? I would run getCompiledDelete() on your $builder - copy the code and run it directly on the database to check.
